# Javascript onclick event not attaching

Tags: javascript, html, onclick

I'm attempting to attach and onclick event to an img tag that I created in Javascript, but for some reason it does not want to attach. In my current code, I have:

```
var img = document.createElement('img');
img.src = pictures[picIndex][0];
img.alt = 'pic';
img.id = "picture_" + picIndex;
img.onclick = function() { alert('click') };
document.getElementById('container').appendChild(img);
```

But when I load my site, I get everything but the onclick event, and clicking the image does nothing:

```
<img src=".." alt="pic" id="picture_3">
```

Why isn't it being appended? I've also tried

```
img.onclick = myFunction;

function myFunction() {
    alert('click');
}
```

and the same thing happens. If I manually edit the img tag to include the onclick function, the function executes just fine, but I can't for the life of me figure out why it isn't attaching when I create the element.

Comment: Just edited it. I just mistyped when writing the question

Answer (score 0):

If you copy and pasted your code in, it looks to be a typo

```
img.onlclick =
```

should be

```
img.onclick =
```

Here is a demo Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/mifi79/CE7PP/

Your problem may be in the ordering- if your JS is on the page prior to the `<div id="container"></div>` (for example in the `<head>`), the `document.getElementById` will not be able to operate on it as it does not yet exist.

The onclick event won't show up inline in the HTML because the image was instantiated as a Javascript object and the onclick handler exists as a property on the image object. I created an updated Fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/mifi79/CE7PP/1/) that outputs the value of the image objects onclick property to the console.

Comment: Ah, I didn't copy/paste, I just transcribed it wrong. I have onclick in my code

Comment: My code is at the end of my HTML, and I have no errors in my console, so I'm assuming that is able to grab the element, especially since the image shows up with all the other attributes, just not onclick

Comment: The on click won't show up inline in the HTML as you created and appended the element with Javascript- it is present on the Javascript object that you instantiated when calling document.createElement('img')

Comment: I created an updated Fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/mifi79/CE7PP/1/) that outputs the value of the onclick property to the console to better illustrate what I am saying.

Comment: Okay, that explains why it isn't showing up in the HTML itself, but my onclick function is still not executing when I click on the image. This is only a small snippet of my code, so maybe I should look at it more in depth to see if I can find the problem

Comment: In that case, you are likely correct to think it is something else in the code. You could always post more of your code or fork my Fiddle and add the rest of your code so that we can look at it further.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your event is not working because you're not using the addEventListener method for non-IE browsers. Perhaps try this.

```
img.addEventListener('click', function () { /* your function here */ }, false);

/* MS fallback */

(img.attachEvent) ? img.attachEvent('onclick', function () { /* func here */ }) : img.addEventListener('click', function () { /* func here */ }, false);
```